# Printing Issue : Setting Paper feed

Tags: cocoa, macos, printing

How to get the paper feed, to set it and to obtain the list of available paper feed on a printer ?
I need to specify the paper tray number from which the paper has to be printed without  putting up the print dialog box in cocoa?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why don't you want to display the print dialog?

Comment: I am write a command line program , where i dont need to put print setting dialog. So ant idea how to set up the paper tray number without dialog ????

Answer (score 0):

Though it is an old thread. There aren't may answers about this problem on the internet.
I succeeded in making it work by setting the InputSlot key on the [printInfo printSettings] dictionary.

```
[[myPrintInfo printSettings] setObject:@"Tray5" forKey:@"InputSlot"]
```

It might or might not work for you as I don't know how printer dependent this setting is.